# Why shouldn't TCP bindings be used outside a firewall?

Tags: wcf, networking, tcp

I have read somewhere that TCP bindings can't be used outside a firewall. I have not understood the reason for this. Could somebody help with an elaborate answer. 
Where does TCP protocol comes into picture then when data is transferred using web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firewalls usually block incoming TCP connections. You need to configure the firewall to open the port that you want to listen on. That's really all there is to using WCF behind a firewall.

The same is true for HTTP bindings because they, too, work over TCP.

Comment: If http bindings also work on TCP, then how does reliable session management occur through them because TCP gives session ability like - session management, ordered messaging etc but HTTP binding doesnot provide all these features.

Comment: TCP knows nothing about HTTP or sessions. It is a stream of bytes, nothing more. The application can implement any protocol any feature on top of TCP if it wants to. It's the choice of the author of the WCF binding.